/etc/docker/daemon.json problem? (docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container)
I installed docker. At first, it worked normally when I tested with hello-world.
There was no /etc/docker/daemon.json file.
But I made daemon.json file with its content :
{
    "runtimes": {
        "nvidia": {
            "path": "nvidia-container-runtime",
            "runtimeArgs": []
        }
    },
    "default-runtime": "nvidia"
}

hello-world example did not worked. (I restarted dockerd, and dockerd was in the process)
$ ps ax | grep docker
   6140 ?        Ssl    1:18 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
  28210 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto docker

error massage is:
$ docker run hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: unable to retrieve OCI runtime error (open /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/664f6606a440194bcd546ed9c1c13f4672ee3e492c5d6dad3b0ec419aa66f0f5/log.json: no such file or directory): exec: "nvidia-container-runtime": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

If I deleted daemon.json, hello-world example worked again.
I added to daemon.json with these lines:
"containerd": "/run/containerd/containerd.sock",
"hosts": [],

=> And, dockerd did not start.
If I delete daemon.json, dockerd start properly, and hello-world example worked again.
I want to use daemon.json (because of nvidia runtime).
Please help me.
